# I am getting False when print form.validate_on_submit() in wtforms and i set secret key also

Tags: validation, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

When i enter Email in login.html and click on submit i am unable to print what they entered and i am getting **form.validate_on_submit = False**

Please help me to solve my problem.

This is my main.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "hi this key is secret"


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField(label="Email", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField(label="Submit")


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(app.secret_key)
    email = None
    print(form.validate_on_submit())
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.validate_on_submit())
        email = form.email.data
        form.email.data = ""
    else:
        print("form not submitted")
    return render_template("login.html", form=form, email=email)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Jinja Template (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            {% if email %}
            <h1>Your Email Is</h1>
            <h3>{{ email }}</h3>
            {% else %}
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form method="post" action="{{ url_for("login") }}">
                    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                    {{ form.email.label }} {{ form.email(size=20) }}
                    {{ form.submit() }}
                </form>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Thankyou In Advance**

Comment: You do not see what has been entered because currently you do not print it. Add this line in your code : `print(form.email.data)`

Comment: When i add it after if validate_on_submit then it won't print because validate_on_submit  is False and if i add it before if statement then the form is not filled yet, that's the problem @Tobin

Comment: Another problem I see in your code is that you have 2 templates `index.html` and `login.html`. You render your form with template `login.html` but all the logic for managing the form is in template `index.html`. You should move this code into the `login.html` file so that Flask validates your form.

Comment: In `login` function, you're just providing the secret key but not the data entered by the user. So, try using `form = LoginForm(request.form)`. And there is no need of using `form.email.data = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the right way
main.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.csrf import CsrfProtect
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "hi this key is secret"
csrf = CsrfProtect(app)


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField(label="Email", validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField(label="Password", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField(label="Submit")


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(formdata=request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password.data
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Jinja template

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('login') }}" novalidate>
                {{ form.csrf_token }}
                <p>
                {{ form.email.label }} <br>{{ form.email(size=20) }}
                    {% for err in form.email.errors %}
                    <span style="color: red">{{ err }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </p>
                <p>
                {{ form.password.label }}<br> {{ form.password(size=20) }}
                    {% for err in form.password.errors %}
                    <span style="color: red">{{ err }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </p>
                {{ form.submit() }}
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This one worked for me hope will work for everyone